# Why does printf return an int instead of a size_t in C

Tags: c, printf

Shouldn't the return be of type `size_t` instead? Because the size of objects in C is of this type, including the string passed to `printf`.

Comment: It's just historical - you can't easily change these things after the fact without breaking existing code, and there is no real motivation when the output from a single `printf` is unlikely to exceed 32k, let alone 2G.

Comment: @PaulR does this mean, it should be of type `size_t`?

Comment: Remember that the [`printf` return value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Return_value) can be *negative*. The [`size_t` type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is unsigned.

Comment: Back when `printf` was designed, there was no `size_t` and people used `int`s. Changing it to `size_t` would break some old code, so they can’t do that; if they were to design `printf` from scratch now they probably would use `size_t`.

Comment: @BiteBytes: if you were defining the stdio API now rather than 40 years ago you might well make it `size_t` or `ssize_t`, but it really makes no difference for any real world example that I can think of.

Comment: @PaulR That’s not a standard C type; you’d be more likely to end up with `size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` being special, I think.

Comment: `size_t` isn't good cause you need a way to signal errors, and you can't use 0 for that because 0 is kind of a legitimate output count for `printf`. I think I'd use ` ssize_t`/`ptrdiff_t`/`long` if I was doing my own `printf`.

Comment: You might also ask why [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) takes an `int` as its size argument, and the reasoning is the same — historical.  There are probably a number of other functions from the standard C library (and even from the POSIX libraries) with similar issues.

Comment: If you ask me, this suggestion would leave C *even less consistent* than it currently is, and we already have a problem with C becoming less and less consistent when it was designed to *reduce* dependence upon inconsistent machinerisms. I've been thinking, and I reckon all return values for such side-effecty functions should *all* be `int`, indicating success/failure (as the return value of `main`).

Comment: IMO, the return type should be `size_t` with an alternate mechanism for the function to return a boolean flag concerning success.

Comment: @chux it might need more than a boolean.

Comment: @BiteBytes A "success or not" would need only a boolean.

Comment: @chux, but does printf returns only one kind of errors? I thought there is a bunch of negative numbers. If printf needs to report only, whether an error occured or not, SIZE_MAX could've been reserved for this specific purpose.

Comment: @BiteBytes Yes if `printf()` was somehow to return descriptive  error information to indicate details on various errors, it would likely need more than a boolean.  Yet then what bit width is needed?, 8, 32, 128?  That error info may include a error index, line number, sequence number, copy of input parameters, .... There is no upper bound. I still maintain to indicate success or not, a boolean would suffice.  The size of the packet of error information is highly dependent on coding needs.

Comment: @BiteBytes `SIZE_MAX` could have been reserved for this specific purpose.  Note that C std lib. does this with `mbrtoc16()` functions, reserving `(size_t)(-3)`, `(size_t)(-2)`, `(size_t)(-1)` for special meaning.  A sad but consistent part of the C std lib is that it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why printf returns an int in C?
>   Shouldn't be of type `size_t` instead?

It could have been, but certainly an early design decision was to accommodate a return value of the negative `EOF` to indicate error.

`size_t` was something of an afterthought in early design choices.  Many functions used `int` where `size_t` is used now in those *pre-standard* days.

---

`fprintf()` has an *environmental limit* "The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095.", so any print that is attempting *long* output may run into that limit before `INT_MAX/SIZE_MAX` concerns.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added note: in 1970, the price of RAM was about [$0.70, about 1/2 labor hour per byte](http://www.statisticbrain.com/average-historic-price-of-ram/).  Early design choices need to consider the very expensive cost of computers and tactics used to lessen code/memory space.  `int` is simple.

Comment: So `printf`, for one reason, or another, doesn't comply to the standard?
Because it uses an `int` to hold the number of characters.

Comment: @BiteBytes `printf()` an extraordinary common function in those pre-standard days (1970s - 1989), became the target to match once the standard 1989 was created.  That creation did not attempt to break existing practice where it could avoid it.  `printf()` complies to the standard because it is the standard on which C89 was based.

Comment: Ok, but what is the right way to check the return of snprintf?  The "obvious" way: `char buff[N];`  `size_t sz = sizeof(buff);`  `int n = snprintf(buff, sz, "...");`  `if (n < sz) ...` gives rise to warnings about comparing signed and unsigned.

Comment: @JohnHascalln Note that `n < 0` indicates an encoding error.  `if (n < 0 || (uintmax_t) n >= sz) error();` should certainly cover all platforms.

Comment: If anyone's wondering where that "environmental limit" came from: http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html

Comment: `write` syscall returns `ssize_t` and I don't think it's any less ancient, is it?

Comment: @JohnHascall Update to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740276/why-does-printf-return-an-int-instead-of-a-size-t-in-c/45740412#comment89569537_45740412), use `if (n < 0 || (unsigned) n >= sz) error();`.  No need for a wider cast.

Answer (score 1):

You're largely right - actually `printf` should return a larger type, since it's theoretically possible to output many more bytes than the size of the largest object that can fit in memory, e.g. `printf("%s%s", largest_string, largest_string)` or even more trivial examples using field widths/precisions.

The reason is just a historical mistake that we're stuck with. It's particularly bad with `snprintf`, which is artificially limited to `INT_MAX` and is forced to return an error if you attempt to create a longer string with it.

Comment: There is still the problem of returning negative numbers. To indicate error.  
If it was up to right now to redesign it, what would you do?

Comment: @BiteBytes: Either use a type sufficiently large that the signed form of the type could be used, or use `(T)-1`, where `T` is an unsigned type, as the error indication. Note that this works conveniently with `snprintf` where `retval>=n` is the error condition (truncation or error causing negative return) that you need to check for anyway.

Comment: @R.. Use `(T)-1` is a good idea.  `int retval = snprintf(... size_t n, ...` and `retval>=n` works well aside from fantasy platforms where `INT_MAX > SIZE_MAX` for the `retval>=n` is a signed compare.  `error = retval < 0 || retval >= n;` always works.

Comment: @chux: Indeed, fantasy platforms are a problem there, but it wouldn't be a problem if `snprintf` actually returned `size_t` or some unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

Back then compilers did not require a function declaration in order to call a function. The return type of a function without declaration or with unspecified return type is `int` - the *implicit int* rule. Some code called `printf` without bothering with pesky `#include <stdio.h>`.